# Button tag that links to another html page

Tags: html

I am working on a form in html. When the user clicks the submit button, it should take them to a verification page (another html file) on my website. However, when I click submit, it looks like it did nothing, since it didn't go to another page.

I have the form linked to a google spreadsheet, and when the user clicks submit, it does the intended purpose (sends the information to the form). However, I also would like it to go to another page. I used the  tag with href before the  tag and I also tried it after the  tag. It does go to another page when I put the  tag after the  tag, but the information submitted doesn't go to the form. I am thinking of using onclick (actually tried it... didn't work), but I don't know JavaScript very well.

```
    <form  class= "form" name="submit-to-google-sheet">
        <input class= "inputbox" name= "first_name" type= "text" placeholder= "First Name" required>
        <input class= "inputbox" name= "last_name" type= "text" placeholder= "Last Name" required>
        <input class= "inputbox" name= "email_address" type= "email" placeholder= "Email" required>

        <button type="submit">Send</button> 
    </form>

    <script>
        const scriptURL = 'https://samplegooglesite/exec'
        const form = document.forms['submit-to-google-sheet']

        form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
            e.preventDefault()
            fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
            .then(response => console.log('Success!', response))
            .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
        })
    </script>
```

This code here will submit the information to the form, just no new page is displayed after clicking the send button. No errors pop up. Thank you for the help.

Comment: you have `e.preventDefault()` which prevents the expected behavior of the form tag, you'll have to redirect them yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not redirecting the user, when the form is succesfully completed, in the `then()` method you need to redirect them like so

```
    <form  class= "form" name="submit-to-google-sheet">
        <input class= "inputbox" name= "first_name" type= "text" placeholder= "First Name" required>
        <input class= "inputbox" name= "last_name" type= "text" placeholder= "Last Name" required>
        <input class= "inputbox" name= "email_address" type= "email" placeholder= "Email" required>

        <button type="submit">Send</button> 
    </form>

    <script>
        const scriptURL = 'https://samplegooglesite/exec'
        const form = document.forms['submit-to-google-sheet']

        form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
            e.preventDefault()
            fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
            .then(response => { window.location.href = 'https://yourwebsite.com'; })
            .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
        })
    </script>
```